# Parsing a certain string in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

Let's say I have such a string: `[a b c d e f]`. I would like to extract those characters and create a char array. Here is how I did it. Seems to be working:

```
var test = GetThemOut("[a b c d e f]");

// ...

public static char[] GetThemOut(string array)
{
    return array
        .Trim('[', ']')
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(x => x[0])
        .ToArray();
}
```

Is there a simpler and a cleaner way to accomplish this? Well, it seems for me that my solution is really stupid and the language could provide a better one.

Still learning the language, trying to grasp tricks. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Alternative, as suggested:

```
public static char[] GetThemOut(string array)
{
    return array
        .Trim('[', ']')
        .Replace(" ", "")
        .ToCharArray();
}
```

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) `String.ToCharArray` is what you're looking for. Use the MSDN! Also there's context sensitive help in VS that should have clued you in on it.

Comment: Are there any other characters your likely to want to remove?

Comment: @DarrenS I just want to extract all the characters that are between those brackets [...]

Comment: @Randolph No .ToCharArray() will work. Instead of your Split you can Replace to remove your spaces then use .ToCharArray()

Comment: OK, right, sorry for not understanding before :) Thanks!

Comment: You could also use LINQ: `array.Except(new[]{'[',']',' ']}.ToArray()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another flavor which uses [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var test = GetThemOut("[a b c d e f]");

public static char[] GetThemOut(string array)
{
    return array.Trim('[', ']')
                .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                .ToArray();                          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
    public static char[] GetThemOut(string array)
    {
        return array.Trim('[', ']').Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToCharArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filetr it with `Char.IsLetter` or `Char.IsLetterOrDigit`:

```
public static char[] GetThemOut(string array)
{
    return array.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand parsing from a traditional perspective; consider this example:

```
    static char[] ParseCharSequence(string s)
    {
        s = s.Trim();

        if (s.Length > 1 && s[0] == '[' && s[s.Length - 1] == ']')
        {
            char[] array = new char[s.Length / 2];

            int depositor = 0;
            int offset = -1;
            int boundary = s.Length - 1;

            for (int i = 1; i < boundary; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] != ' ')
                {
                    if (i == offset + 1)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Conflict at index {0}.", i));
                    }

                    array[depositor++] = s[i];
                    offset = i;
                }
            }

            Array.Resize(ref array, depositor);

            return array;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This function is 10 times faster than:

```
return s.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Where(x => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
```

Either way, the suggested format is nonsensical because characters are implicitly separable. However, if you wish to separate strings as a next assignment, then you would indeed require a delimiter. Note that space is not recommendable as a delimiter, because it has no explicit significance, reading it causes eye-sore.